# Filter nested array for specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple array like this:

```
const test = [{
  test: 1,
  key: [{
    yes: true,
    no: null
  },{
    yes: true,
    no: null
  },{
    yes: false,
    no: null
  }]
},
{
  test: true,
  key: [{
    yes: true,
    no: null
  }]
},
{
  test: null,
  key: [{
    yes: null,
    no: null
  }]
}
];
```

And I want to return an array which will only include items where `test` is truthy (e.g. 1). And the `key` array inside of `test` will only include objects with a truthy value for `key.yes`.

So the expected output is:

```
[
   {
     test: 1,
     key: [{yes: true, no: null},{yes: true, no: null}]
   },
   {
     test: true,
     key: [{yes: true, no: null}]
   }
];
```

I tried to achieve this by using a simple filter like this:

`const filtered = test.filter(obj => obj.test && obj.key.filter(item => item.yes).length > 0)`

but this returns also the values of the `key` array which are `false`.

Any ideas why?

Comment: do you want a new array with new key array or mutate the old one?

Comment: @NinaScholz A new array is perfectly fine which is why I tried using `.filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a new outer array and new inner arrays, because the outer filtering does not change the inner arrays. If you mutate the inner array and filter the outer array, you mutate the given data.

For getting an independent result, you could check `test` and if truthy filter `key` and get a new object for the result set.

```js
var test = [{ test: 1, key: [{ yes: true, no: null }, { yes: true, no: null }, { yes: false, no: null }] }, { test: true, key: [{ yes: true, no: null }] }, { test: null, key: [{ yes: null, no: null }] }],
    result = test.reduce((r, { test, key }) => {
        if (test) {
            r.push({ test, key: key.filter(({ yes }) => yes) });
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to filter each individual `key` array as well.

```
// array where `test` is truthy
const filtered = test.filter(({ test }) => !!test);

// array where sub-arrays are filterd
const final = filtered.map(({ key }) => key.filter(({ yes }) => !!yes));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first filter main array and then remap to new filtering subbarray, for example:

```
const filtered = test
   .filter(obj => obj.test && obj.key.some(item => item.yes))
   .map(d => {d.test, key: d.key.filter(item => item.yes));
```

Or probably filter array by key.yes a moment later:

```
const filtered = test
   .filter(obj => obj.test)
   .map(d => {d.test, key = d.key.filter(item => item.yes))
   .filter(s => s.key);
```